# Find specular light

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, visible-light

I'm studying the specular light so I'm in a situation like this:

[image]

where:

- $\vec l$ is the unit vector in the direction of the light source
- $\vec m$ is the normal to the surface
- $\vec v$ is the unit vector in the direction of sight
- $\vec r$ is the reflected ray.

Also the angles between $\vec l$ and $\vec m$ and among $\vec m$ and $\vec r$ are equal.

The book then calculates $\vec r$ this:

$$\vec l + \vec r = 2(\vec l \cdot \vec m)\vec m$$

and then:

$$\vec r = 2(\vec l \cdot \vec m)\vec m - \vec l$$

All this is accompanied by the following image:

[image]

What I don't understand are the calculations that have been made. Why $\vec l + \vec r = 2(\vec l \cdot \vec m)\vec m$?
Could someone explain them step by step?

Answer (score 0):

Start with the expression:

$$ \vec l + \vec r = 2(\vec l \cdot \vec m)\vec m $$

From the definition of the dot product $\vec l \cdot \vec m = |\vec l| |\vec m| \cos\theta$ and since $\vec l$ and $\vec m$ are unit vectors $\vec l \cdot \vec m = \cos\theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec l$ and $\vec m$. So the equation becomes:

$$ \vec l + \vec r = 2\cos\theta\,\vec m $$

Now let's draw the diagram for adding $\vec l$ and $\vec r$:

[image: Vector addition]

The horizontal components of $\vec l$ and $\vec r$ are $-\sin\theta$ and $\sin\theta$ respectively (remember $\vec l$ and $\vec r$ are unit vectors) so when we add the horizontal components we get zero. The vertical components of $\vec l$ and $\vec r$ are both $\cos\theta$ so adding them gives $2\cos\theta$, and this is in the $\vec m$ direction so we get:

$$ \vec l + \vec r = 2\cos\theta\,\vec m $$

And that proves the equation we started out with:

$$ \vec l + \vec r = 2(\vec l \cdot \vec m)\vec m $$

The second equation is simply obtained by subtracting $\vec l$ from both sides.